# Converter declaração XML do Spring para código Java

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Alguém pode me ajudar a converter o código XML do Spring que está logo abaixo em um código Java?

```xml
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <property name="dialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.dialect.SpringStandardDialect" />
            <ref bean="pagesDialect" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Vai aí o meu `WebAppConfig`:

```java
package com.ghtecnologia.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ghtecnologia"})
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    // Maps resources path to webapp/resources
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    // Provides internationalization of messages
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor LocaleChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localechangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        return localechangeInterceptor;
    }
}
```

Comment: edite sua pergunta com mais informações

Comment: Eu quero configurara o "Bean" na configuração da aplicação em java.

Comment: Sera que não aparece uma viva alma para me ajudar.

Comment: Na minha aplicação já tenho WebAppConfig, o que eu quero é codidificar no meu WebAppConfig bean que postei.

Comment: @GeraldoTorres conseguiu fazer a conversão?

Answer (score 1):

Salve!

Pelo visto você quer configurar o contexto do Spring via classe utilizando a anotação `@Configuration`, certo?

Se for isso, utilize essa configuração como referência:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({MinhaConfigDeServicos.class})
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:META-INF/minhaspropriedades.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // vc pode utilizar essa referencia para capturar as propriedades
    @Inject
    protected Environment environment;

    // aqui eh o seu template resolver.
    // eu uso o thymeleaf. mas eh aqui que vc configura de acordo com o seu XML da pergunta
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

O segredo está em estender a classe `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. É ela que dará suporte para a sua configuração Spring MVC.

Outro ponto é que você vai precisar inicializar o contexto. Graças ao Servlet 3 você não precisa mais configurar nada do `web.xml`. Basta criar um `ServletInitializer` no seu `classpath`. Dessa forma:

```
public class SpringMvcWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // a sua configuracao web
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o seu contexto vai ser inicializado junto com a Web App.

Se ainda tiver dúvidas, coloque nos comentários que eu tento lhe ajudar.

**EDIT:**
Se puder, dê mais informações sobre o seu ambiente (servidor de aplicação, versão do Spring utilizada, etc.) para poder formular melhor a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Partindo da declaração do seu `bean` no XML, vamos primeiro declarar o *template resolver*, ficará parecido com isto:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return resolver;
}
```

O *template engine*, `bean` que você tem necessidade de configurar ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(this.templateResolver());

    final Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<>();
    dialects.add(new SpringStandardDialect());

    // inclua o outro dialeto, como não sei o tipo não coloquei, já que pode ser um customizado
    // dialects.add(pagesDialect);

    engine.setDialects(dialects);
    return engine;
}
```

Por fim, além do *template resolver* e também do *tempalte engine* você pode precisar do *view resolver*, ele será algo como isto:

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    final ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine());
    return resolver;
}
```

Se for usar apenas `thymeleaf` você não precisar do outro *view resolver* configurado, então pode remover o `bean` criado em `setupViewResolver`.